# Creating Table Filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have a simple table with 3 columns like so

```
table
  thead
    th Element
    th Owner
    th Progress
  tbody
    == render :partial => "element_row" :collection => @elements :as => table_element
```

Each element is unique, and one owner may have several elements. There are a few different types of "progress" e.g. `"started"`, `"not started"`, and `"completed"`.

I want to create a few links that filter the table. For example, I want to create an **started** link where when the user clicks on the link, the table is filtered down to only show rows where `"started"` is displayed. Another example of a filter is by owner.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a gem to help you, **[Ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack)** is a great, popular, and active project for searching *(and by extension, **filtering**)* ActiveRecord data.

If you check out Ernie's [demo site](http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/users/advanced_search) you can see how the search parameters modify the URL through GET queries. You could easily create links like your desired **started** link to mock these GET form requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on the server side, add a filter method to the controller that uses link parameters to filter the @elements.

If you selecting @elements from the database using ActiveRecord, you could do:

```
@elements = Element.where(progress: params[:progress])
```

If you just want to filter the @elements in memory, you could do:

```
@elements = @elements.select{ |element| element.progress == params[:progress] }
```